# 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__' when I try to return a dict

Tags: python, django

Traceback Switch to copy-and-paste view

```
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.7.3-   py2.7.egg\django\core\handlers\base.py in get_response
                response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) ...

 ▶ Local vars

 c:\mystudio\tag_study\views.py in recite_words
        VariablesNew = next_word(request) ...

▶ Local vars

c:\mystudio\tag_study\views.py in next_word
                p_t_set.type7_status = change["type_status"] ...

▶ Local vars

return (control)
```

I think I build a dict in the `chossen_old_words` function and return it, But when I try use the dict, it shows the following error:

> 'NoneType' object has no attribute '**getitem**'

I do not know what produces this error. Is there some basics I missed？

Comment: Your functions don't return anything as far as i can see. What is the code supposed to do? Views should return a HttpResponse of some kind.

Comment: You are defining your `change` dict in a function `chossen_old_words`. It is not possible to use it in the `next_word` function. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-python-scoping-rules) about the scopes. Also, please consider pep8 for code styling.

Comment: I think the line return (control) should be the last line of the code above. To me it looks like as you are not returning anything from your chossen_old_words function - leaving the function without a return. Can you correct your code so that we can see on what identation level the return (control) is)

Comment: The “return control” exists in my code. I just forgot put "return control" in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any `return` statement in the `chossen_old_words()` function so while you build a dictionary in the function (I suppose it's the `control` one), you don't return it.

When you accept the return value in the `next_word()` function, as I said the `chossen_old_words()` function returns *nothing*. However, in Python every function returns *something* and if you don't return anything explicitly (like in your case), then `None` is returned. Which is exactly what happened to you.

`None`'s type is `NoneType` and it doesn't have any method. You're trying to use it as a dictionary though and as soon as you try and retrieve an item from it, you'll get this error.

I believe this error can be fixed by adding `return control` statement at the end of the `chossen_old_words()` function. Hard to say if there are any other errors though.

BTW, your indentation seems to be off.

Comment: It was a type mistake, I add the return(control) to the code now.

Comment: So did my answer help you? Does it work as expected now? BTW, you don't need to use the parenthesis - `return control` is alright.

Comment: No,it not help,The “return control” exists in my code. I just forgot put "return control" in the question.

Comment: Get rid of the parenthesis. Also, notice what happens if this condition is False: `PersonalRecord.objects.filter(status = type).exists()`. Do you see it?

Comment: Thank for you patient, but it still not work. I decide to rewrite the function.